# How can i make that linq request simpler

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have lists of following models:

```
public record Project(
    int Id,
    int AuthorId,
    int TeamId,
    string Name,
    string Description,
    DateTime CreatedAt,
    DateTime Deadline)

public record Task(
    int Id,
    int ProjectId,
    int PerformerId,
    string Name,
    string Description,
    TaskState State,
    DateTime CreatedAt,
    DateTime? FinishedAt)

public record User(
    int Id,
    int? TeamId,
    string FirstName,
    string LastName,
    string Email,
    DateTime RegisteredAt,
    DateTime BirthDay)
```

Task to wrote Linq that retrieve UserInfoDto by user ID. UserInfoDto has the following structure:
UserDto User - user
ProjectDto LastProject - User's last project (based on creation date). Should be null if the user has no projects.
int LastProjectTasksCount - Total number of tasks under the last project. Should be 0 if the user has no projects or if the project has no tasks.
int NotFinishedOrCanceledTasksCount - Total number of unfinished or canceled tasks (State = ToDo or InProgress or Canceled) for the user. Should be 0 if the user has no tasks.(user's task not project's)
TaskDto LongestTask - User's longest task in terms of duration (end date - creation date). Make sure to consider the case when the task is not yet completed.(user's task not project's)

What i have:

```
public async Task<UserInfoDto> GetUserInfoAsync(int userId)
    {

        var tasks = await _dataProvider.GetTasksAsync();
        var users = await _dataProvider.GetUsersAsync();
        var projects = await _dataProvider.GetProjectsAsync();

        return users.Join(tasks,
            user => user.Id,
            task => task.PerformerId,
            (user, task) => new
            {
                User = user,
                UserTask = task,
            }).Join(projects,
            firstJoin => firstJoin.User.Id,
            project => project.AuthorId,
            (firstJoin, userProject) => new
            {
                User = firstJoin.User,
                UserTask = firstJoin.UserTask,
                UserProject = userProject,
            }).Join(tasks,
            secondJoin => secondJoin.UserProject.Id,
            task => task.ProjectId,
            (secondJoin, task) => new
            {
                User = secondJoin.User,
                UserTask = secondJoin.UserTask,
                UserProject = secondJoin.UserProject,
                ProjectTask = task,
            })
            .Where(r=>r.User.Id == userId)
            .GroupBy(r=>r.User)
            .Select(g=>
            {
                var lastUserProject = g.Select(r=>r.UserProject)
                    .MaxBy(p=>p.CreatedAt);
                var lastProjectTaskCount = g.Select(r=>r.ProjectTask).Distinct()
                    .Count(p=>p.ProjectId == lastUserProject.Id);
                var notFinishedOrCanceledTasksCount = g.Select(r=>r.UserTask).Distinct()
                    .Count(t=>t.State == TaskState.ToDo
                    || t.State == TaskState.InProgress
                    || t.State == TaskState.Canceled);
                var longestTask = g.Select(r=>r.UserTask)
                    .Where(t=>t.FinishedAt is not null)
                    .MaxBy(t=> t.FinishedAt - t.CreatedAt);
                var user = g.Key;

                return _mapper
                    .Map<UserInfoDto>((user,
                    lastUserProject,
                    lastProjectTaskCount,
                    longestTask,
                    notFinishedOrCanceledTasksCount));
            }).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Comment: You cannot possibly materialize the whole database and filter and join client side. You need to move joins and filters to the database as much as you can.

Comment: I get data from api not from database

Comment: Then you need to extend the api. Just think about it: right now you get _all_ users,  projects,  tasks. [_All_ of them](https://youtu.be/74BzSTQCl_c)... that won't fly.

Comment: i know, but it is just a task from programming academy to practise linq methods

Comment: Unbelievable. Ok then this can be considered completely "academic", is that correct?

Comment: You seem to be under the impression you need to stuff everything into one linq expression. Why is that?

Comment: It is said in task to do

Comment: Can you add the exact wording of the assignment? I've seen a lot of bs from "academies" but I still want to give them the shadow of doubt it could be a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to the answer it to look at the relationships of User, Task and Project. Task is the object that has foreign keys into User and Project. But not every user has a Task and not every Project has a Task. So start out by left outer joining User to Task and then left join that to Project, i.e. two left joins. In Linq left joins are achieved with GroupJoin/SelectMany/DefaultIfEmpty. Once this is done, group by the User, finally aggregate all the related tasks/projects associated to each user.

The code that follows returns:

```
FirstName | Last Project | LastProjectTaskCount | NotFinishedOrCancelledCount
----------+--------------+----------------------+----------------------------
Tom       | Catch Jerry  | 4                    | 2
Spike     | null         | 0                    | 0
```

```
void Main()
{
    // Setup some dummy data
    var projects = GetProjects();
    var tasks = GetTasks(); 
    var users = GetUsers();

    // Left-join Users to Tasks
    var userInfo = users
        .GroupJoin(tasks,
            u => u.Id, 
            t => t.PerformerId, 
            (u, t) => new { User = u, Tasks = t })
        .SelectMany(
            ut => ut.Tasks.DefaultIfEmpty(),
            (x, y) => new { x.User, Task = y })
        // Now left-join user/task to project
        .GroupJoin(projects,
            ut => ut.Task?.ProjectId,
            p => p.Id,
            (ut, p) => new {UserTask = ut, Projects = p })
        .SelectMany(
            utp => utp.Projects.DefaultIfEmpty(),
            (x, y) => new { x.UserTask.User, x.UserTask.Task, Project = y })
        // Now group by User
        .GroupBy(utp => utp.User)
        .Select(grp =>
        {
            // The grp.Key is the User object
            var user = grp.Key;
            
            // Here's how to return the latest task in the group
            var lastProject = grp.Aggregate((g1, g2) => g1.Task.CreatedAt > g2.Task.CreatedAt ? g1 : g2).Project;
            
            // Return the UserInfoDto details. 
            return new
            {
                user.FirstName,
                LastProject = lastProject?.Name,
                
                // Here's how to count the number of tasks associated with that user and the last task
                LastProjectTaskCount = grp.Count(g => g.Task != null && g.Project.Id == lastProject?.Id),
                
                // Here's how to count all specific tasks in the group
                NotFinishedOrCancelledCount = grp.Where(g => g.Task?.ProjectId == lastProject?.Id).Count(g => 
                    g.Task?.State == TaskState.InProgress || 
                    g.Task?.State == TaskState.ToDo ||
                    g.Task?.State == TaskState.Cancelled)
            };
        });
}

public List<User> GetUsers()
{
    return new List<User>() {
        new User { Id = 1, FirstName = "Tom" },
        new User { Id = 2, FirstName = "Spike" }
        };
}

public List<Project> GetProjects()
{
    return new List<Project>() {
        new Project { Id = 1, Name = "Rest Up", CreatedAt = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-10) },
        new Project { Id = 2, Name = "Catch Jerry", CreatedAt = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-5) },
        new Project { Id = 3, Name = "Stop the Cat", CreatedAt = DateTime.Now },
        };
}

public List<Task> GetTasks()
{
    return new List<Task>() {
        new Task { Id = 1, ProjectId = 1, PerformerId = 1, Name = "Sleep", State = TaskState.Finished, CreatedAt = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-5)},
        new Task { Id = 1, ProjectId = 2, PerformerId = 1, Name = "Set Trap", State = TaskState.Finished, CreatedAt = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-4)},
        new Task { Id = 2, ProjectId = 2, PerformerId = 1, Name = "Mouse Walks Into Trap", State = TaskState.Finished, CreatedAt = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-3)},
        new Task { Id = 3, ProjectId = 2, PerformerId = 1, Name = "Activate Trap", State = TaskState.InProgress, CreatedAt = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-2)},
        new Task { Id = 4, ProjectId = 2, PerformerId = 1, Name = "Eat Mouse", State = TaskState.ToDo, CreatedAt = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-2)}
        };
}


public enum TaskState { ToDo, InProgress, Cancelled, Finished }

public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime Deadline { get; set; }
}

public class Task
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public int PerformerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public TaskState State { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime? FinishedAt { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? TeamId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public DateTime RegisteredAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDay { get; set; }
}
```